# Tuning motor temperature

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, temperature, motor-controller

I have a DC motor, running in two modes, slow and fast. I will need to run the motor in FAST mode only. The motor is already running for 10 years. The motor experiences variable load.
According to the graph in fig 1, the red line shows the Fast speed with 10 Nm force. The blue line shows a slow speed of 15 Nm. And the top line is the test run in fig 2.

The motor runs for 6 hours at FAST speed. At FAST speed, the motor temperature raises from 25 °C to 90 °C during these 6 hours with a 10 Nm force at 1.4 A current. And stays at 90 °C. With 10 Nm, the motor reaches 90 °C, which is under the temperature limit.

The motor temperature limit is 110°C before it shuts off.

[image]
Fig 1

When I increase the load on the motor to 26 Nm, the motor temperature reaches 110°C in 30 minutes, and the motor shuts off.

To solve this issue, I have to run the motor at certain times at fast and slow speeds. I put in a microcontroller to switch between these two modes. For this, I have run a test that kept the motor running for 129 minutes (2 hours and 15 minutes) by switching between fast and slow modes.

[image]
Fig 2

My goal is to keep the motor running without stopping.

As shown in Fig 2, starting in the first 25 minutes, the motor reaches 80°C. Afterwards, I put the motor on slow speed for 40 minutes, and the temperature keeps rising to 89°C. Then I put the motor into the fast mode for 10 minutes, and so on, until the temperature reaches 110 °C and the motor shuts off.

With doing the above switching from fast to slow, the temperature goes down, and the run time increases to 129 minutes.

I can’t put a thermometer on the motor due to limitations. The only thing I can measure is the current and time.

I need to know what to do to keep the motor temperature lower than 110°C by switching between fast and slow. I am not sure for how long I should run the motor at each speed, so the overall temperature doesn’t reach 110°C and the time increases to 6 hours and more.

Comment: Tips: **N** (newton) is the unit of **force**. **Nm** is the unit of **torque**. You can use the HTML entity `&deg;` to insert the degree symbol in your post (but it doesn't work in the comments).

Comment: Add a fan to the motor shaft?

Comment: Running the motor such that it is barely under the protective shutdown temperature does not sound like it will yield very good reliability (or lifetime of the motor).  So procuring a larger motor or cooling the one you have seems like a much better approach. Also, the ambient temperature will have an approximately 1:1 effect on terminal motor temperature. For every °C the ambient temperature rises, the terminal temperature of the motor will increase by 1°C.

Comment: Most small motors have a built-in fan.  They cool themselves.  If you don't run it fast enough, illogically they get hotter, not cooler.   Your data actually kind of shows this happening (i.e. you're not getting the dramatically lower temps you were hoping for).   I'm with @SpehroPefhany... Get a bigger motor that you don't have to run to it's limits.  If you take what you have to production, you're probably signing up for massive field issues.  Things never work same in the 'real world' as they do in the lab.   i.e. after a few months they'll get dirty and that affects heat dissipation.

Comment: I've seen motors with a smooth metal exterior have a "cooling" tube (copper) soldered or brazed to it.  Then coolant is pumped through the tube, reducing the motor temperature.    But this is a band-aid solution to an undersized-motor problem.

Comment: I can't add other item to the motor, the only option I have is to run it in slow and Fast more for certain of the time. Based on the graph  blue line, then motor is running in slow mode, it is cooler than running in fast mode. So dropping from fast to slow helps a lot

Comment: Your best hope is to develop a model of temp vs speed and use model based control techniques -- but it sounds like you're using the wrong motor to me.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, I can't change the motor. With switching between speeds, I could run the motor for 2 hours. I know the motor can run with 10 Nm torque. With 26 Nm, If it can run for 2 hours with switching speeds in specific time, so there must be a way to increase the 2 hours to more time. I can measure the current and time only.

Comment: You might choose to tell us what you would like to accomplish by moving the motor.   Given that you can't cool the motor, and you can only run at one of two speeds, I think the only answer, short of building a reliable electro-thermal-mechanical model, is somewhere between "run the motor on slow all the time" and "run the motor on slow when it gets hot, and keep it on slow until it cools down"  --- but you haven't told us what you need to achieve.